# How to autofill hundreds of names in a name field for a word document

Tags: ms-office, cpu-word, autofill

So let's say I have 100 employees and I have a word document with a message on it pertaining some new business changes. Is there a way for Microsoft word to autofill the name field of that document to where a 100 of that same document each has a different name of an employee?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can probably use the mail merge option for your problem. I think it will definitely work for you. For more information, you can see how to use mail merge on google. Its especially used for labels, emails, and letters which are in bulk.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).